# Mysterious memory leak in C++ file output function

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, gdb

I hate to do the old "here's some code, what's wrong with it?" but I've been investigating this issue for several days with no progress. This code usually crashes immediately with the debugger off, though occasionally there'll be a space of a few hours where it'll compile and run correctly. With gdb attached it works but leaks memory at about 10 MB per second and eventually crashes when it runs out.

It's definitely this function; no such issues occur when the only call to it is commented out, and calling it less often delays the out-of-memory crash.

```
 //Write a frame of the animation to disk
void draw_frame(int framenum) {
    ofstream fout;
    ostringstream fname;
    fname << "D:\\frames\\" << framenum << ".data";
    fout.open(fname.str(), ios::binary | ios::out);

    unsigned char ***frame;
    frame = new unsigned char ** [WORLDSIZE];
    for (int x = 0; x < WORLDSIZE; x++) {
        frame[x] = new unsigned char * [WORLDSIZE];
        for (int y=0; y < WORLDSIZE; y++) {
            frame[x][y] = new unsigned char [3];
        }
    }

    unsigned long long ***colormix;
    colormix = new unsigned long long ** [WORLDSIZE];
    for (int x = 0; x < WORLDSIZE; x++) {
        colormix[x] = new unsigned long long * [WORLDSIZE];
        for (int y=0; y < WORLDSIZE; y++) {
            colormix[x][y] = new unsigned long long [3];
            for (int z=0; z < 3; z++) {
                colormix[x][y][z]=0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (vector<SmellyObject *>::iterator it = smellythings.begin(); it != smellythings.end(); ++it) {
        SmellyObject *theobj = *it;
        for (int x=0; x < WORLDSIZE; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y < WORLDSIZE; y++) {
                double scentlevel = scentmaps[theobj -> id][x][y];
                double colorlevel = (scentlevel / 10000.0);
                colormix[x][y][0] += theobj->r * colorlevel;
                colormix[x][y][1] += theobj->g * colorlevel;
                colormix[x][y][2] += theobj->b * colorlevel;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x=0; x < WORLDSIZE; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < WORLDSIZE; y++) {
            for (int z=0; z < 3; z++) {
                //cout << colormix[x][y][z] << " ";
                frame[x][y][z] = min(255.0, (colormix[x][y][z] / (double) smellythings.size()));
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x=0; x < WORLDSIZE; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < WORLDSIZE; y++) {
            fout.write((char *) frame[x][y], 3);
        }
    }

    fout.close();

    frame = new unsigned char ** [WORLDSIZE];
    for (int x = 0; x < WORLDSIZE; x++) {
        frame[x] = new unsigned char * [WORLDSIZE];
        for (int y=0; y < WORLDSIZE; y++) {
            for (int z=0; z < WORLDSIZE; z++) {
                //delete[] &frame[x][y][z];
            }
            delete[] frame[x][y];
        }
        delete[] frame[x];
    }
    delete[] frame;

    colormix = new unsigned long long ** [WORLDSIZE];
    for (int x = 0; x < WORLDSIZE; x++) {
        colormix[x] = new unsigned long long * [WORLDSIZE];
        for (int y=0; y < WORLDSIZE; y++) {
            for (int z=0; z < WORLDSIZE; z++) {
                //delete[] &colormix[x][y][z];
            }
            delete[](colormix[x][y]);
        }
        delete[](colormix[x]);
    }
    delete[](colormix);

    return;
}
```

WORLDSIZE is 50, and `scentmaps` is a `std::unordered_map` mapping ints (the .id property of a SmellyObject) to WORLDSIZE x WORLDSIZE arrays of doubles.

Comment: You already use `vector`, why are you using `new[]` and `delete[]` in some parts of the code?

Comment: Do you really need to mess with these pointers _to pointers_ __to pointers__? Why not use a `std::vector` instead? Alright, it could take pretty horrifying forms like `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<char>>>`, but you won't need to allocate memory for the elements, which will save you a lot of time and won't cause headaches while debugging.

Comment: Ouch, when I see `char ***frame` it hurts my eyes... Why do you use 3 levels of indirection ? Can't you just use standard C++ container ?

Comment: @ForceBru Yeah, maybe I should just trash this and start over; I was in "it's 4 AM and the deadline was midnight, just make it work" mode when I wrote this.

Comment: *"investigating this issue for several days"* and still no MCVE?

Comment: @Schilcote -- Please use something [like this](http://ideone.com/ueeN6L).  No loops, no calls to `new[] / delete[]`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame = new unsigned char ** [WORLDSIZE];
```

You allocate this array at the beginning of the function, and proceed to allocate all of its three dimensions, gobbling up a huge amount of memory.

Then, later...

```
fout.close();

frame = new unsigned char ** [WORLDSIZE];
```

... you just reassigned `frame` to another allocated array. The old `frame` pointer is gone, and you've just leaked the metric ton of memory you allocated initially.

Same bug with your other, `colormix` array.

Lesson to be learned from this: the best way to fix bugs is to never make them in the first place. Had you been using C++ containers that properly handle all memory allocations for you, like `std::vector`, this would've never happened. Correctly using the full resources of the C++ library -- containers, iterators, algorithms -- make it logically impossible for many common programming bugs to happen.

Comment: Ah, I copied the loop I used to create the arrays to delete them and forgot to take out the `new[]`s... and then didn't notice I'd done so for two days. This is why I usually avoid C++ altogether... Thanks!

Comment: Had you been using `std::vector`, you would not have needed to copy anything, since the vector would've taken care of the deallocaiton for you, and the bug never would've happened. That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Schilcote: `new[]` is a misfeature of C++ which nobody should use anyway. You use standard container classes which prevent such mistakes. Internally, those container classes use placement new.